# django: cannot run custom authentication backend

Tags: python, django, authentication

I made a custom authentication backend and tried to run it but I found that 
it doesn't run custom authentication and also returns an error.

Below is the source code.

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'welcome.NDDUser'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'welcome.backend.MyCustomBackend',
)
```

**welcome/backend.py**

```
from welcome.models import NDDUser

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyCustomBackend(object):
    # Create an authentication method
    # This is called by the standard Django login procedure.
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            # Try to find a user matching your name
            user = NDDUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except NDDUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        else:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return NDDUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except NDDUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**welcome/views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from welcome.models import NDDUser, University

from welcome.forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user is not None:

            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to doctor search page.
            return redirect('search:index')
        else:
            context = { 'login_error_message' : 'You put the wrong information'}
            return render(request, 'welcome/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'welcome/index.html')
```

**welcome/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    university = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField()
    password1 = forms.CharField(min_length=6)
    password2 = forms.CharField(min_length=6)
    nickname = forms.CharField(max_length=15, min_length=2)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RegisterForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Both passwords r not same.")

        return cleaned_data
```

**welcome/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
                                        BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
                                        )
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class NDDUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, university, password, nickname):
        user = self.model(
                          email=NDDUserManager.normalize_email(email),
                          university=university,
                          nickname=nickname,
                          )

        user.set_password(password)
        #user.full_clean()
        #user.save()
        try:
            user.full_clean()
        except ValidationError as e:
            return e

        user.save()    
        return user

class NDDUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    university = models.ForeignKey('University')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'invalid' : 'Invalid mail address','unique' : 'Already registered email address'})
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length='15', unique=True, error_messages={'unique' : 'Already registered nickname'})

    objects = NDDUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['university', 'password', 'nickname']


class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='20')
    email = models.CharField(max_length='20')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.name, self.email)
```

And I didn't `syncdb` till writing all the code. Finally, after `syncdb` and
run it by eclipse (using pydev), I face the error message below:

```
ERROR    2014-05-09 06:15:49,448 base.py:212] Internal Server Error: /welcome/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/nextdoordoctor/git/NDDWeb/NDDWeb/src/welcome/views.py", line 19, in index
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 60, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 16, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 168, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 398, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 130, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 120, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 202, in execute
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'nddweb.auth_user' doesn't exist")
INFO     2014-05-09 06:15:49,548 module.py:639] default: "POST /welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 500 12787
```

------------------------- more information ------------

Finally I put the AUTH_USER_MODEL definition top of the settings.py and syncdb it works! 
There is no error output like above. But still I have another problem.

When I click submit button of form and post data r send to view.py and authenticate() function doesn't work properly.

Even though I type the correct form data and send it still output that 'You put wrong information'. Django doesn't really import MyCustomBackend I guess..

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `Table 'nddweb.auth_user' doesn't exist` Did you sync the database?

Comment: I finally syncdb and error message disappeared. But I still got a problem again.

Comment: You need to update the question then.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signatures don't match. Your backend needs a `username` and a `password`, yet in your view you try to authenticate your user using an `email` and `password`.

Calling `MyCustomBackend.authenticate` with unsupported keywords will raise a `TypeError`. Django treats this the same as when a backend returns `None`. This way, multiple backends can receive different keyword arguments and still function correctly.

Also note that, though you've set the `USERNAME_FIELD` attribute, your user model still doesn't have a `username` field. It is only used in the `get_username` method, and in the manager's `get_by_natural_key` method. In all other cases, you still have to filter for the actual `email` field.

BTW, at the moment your custom backends doesn't do anything that the default Django backend doesn't do. Unless you need to add more custom functionality, consider using the default backend.